# Ayuda con un Test webdriver con geckodriver y selenium ide

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-ng

estoy usando selenium ide la version mas antigua donde uno puede exportar el script en formato testng driverweb, el tema es que intentado varias formas para poder ejecutar el test pero todavia sigo con problemas con el test, aqui esta el código:

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Geckodriver_Fire\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/ProyectoTesting/index.jsp";
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testCamposValidos() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/ProyectoTesting/index.jsp");
    driver.findElement(By.id("indentificador")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("indentificador")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("indentificador")).sendKeys("19");
    driver.findElement(By.id("monto")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("monto")).sendKeys("600000");
    driver.findElement(By.name("cuotas")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("cuotas")).sendKeys("12");
    driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("20")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("desgravamen")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("protegido")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ap")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("rut")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("rut")).sendKeys("19");
    driver.findElement(By.id("nombre")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("nombre")).sendKeys("nicolas");
    driver.findElement(By.id("apellido")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("apellido")).sendKeys("flores");
    driver.findElement(By.id("renta")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("renta")).sendKeys("600000");
    driver.findElement(By.id("celular")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("celular")).sendKeys("994573188");
    driver.findElement(By.id("telefono")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("telefono")).sendKeys("26451419");
    driver.findElement(By.id("correo")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("correo")).sendKeys("nico@gmail.com");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("regiones"))).selectByVisibleText("Región Metropolitana de Santiago");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("comunas"))).selectByVisibleText("Macul");
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
}

  @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
```

Comment: si agregas las versines es mejor

Answer (score 0):

Verifica el string del `baseUrl` y cómo lo invocas en el `driver.get`.

Así como lo  tienes ahora, el `get` sería a:

```
"http://localhost:8080/ProyectoTesting/index.jsp/ProyectoTesting/index.jsp"
```